# Appcelerator Ti.Blob text property is null

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, file-access

I came across a strange issue while reading files from `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory`. Whenever I want to access the `text` property of the `Ti.Blob` returned by `Ti.Filesystem.File.read()` I get `null`

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'foo.key');
var contents = f.read();
Ti.API.debug('contents: ' + JSON.stringify(contents));
var text = contents.text;
Ti.API.debug('text: ' + JSON.stringify(text)); // is NULL
```

The file was created like so

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'foo.key');
f.write(JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'});
```

I'm developing on Android by the way with 6.0.1.GA

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** it's the file extension that's causing the problem

When looking at the `Ti.Blob` more thoroughly I found that it says `mimeType : application/gpg-keys`. After updating my code above so it uses `foo.json` as filename everything works as expected.